# json.net c# collection serialize

Tags: c#, list, serialization, json.net

I have to build a JSON data that looks like the below. I am using JSON.net in C# to build the structure. 
**{
    "username":"xxxx",
    "password":"yyyy",
    "inputs" : 
    [ 
        {
            "name" : "cccc"
        },
        {
            "name" : "dddd"
        } 
    ]
}**

The C# code looks like this.

```
    **public string MethodName(ref rdServerObjects rdObjects)
    {
        RootObject preJsonData = new RootObject();

        List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();
        Input input = new Input();
        preJsonData.username = "xxxx";
        preJsonData.password = "yyyy";
        input.name = "cccc";
        inputs.Add(input);
        input.name = "dddd";
        inputs.Add(input);
        string postJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(preJsonData);
        return postJsonData;
    }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public List<Input> inputs { get; set; }
}
public class Input
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}**
```

When my code executes, the output comes as:

**{"username":"xxxx","password":"yyyy","inputs":null}**

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? All help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set the `inputs` property of `preJsonData`.

```
    List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();
    Input input = new Input();
    preJsonData.username = "xxxx";
    preJsonData.password = "yyyy";
    input.name = "cccc";
    inputs.Add(input);
    input.name = "dddd";
    inputs.Add(input);
    preJsonData.inputs = inputs; //<-- this bad boy
    string postJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(preJsonData);
    //string postJsonData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(preJsonData);
    return postJsonData;
```

Comment: Thank you...one small issue still hanging. Even after i made the above change, i still get {"username":"xxxx","password":"yyyy","inputs":[{"name":"dddd"},{"name":"dddd"}]}...Looks like the 1st inputs.add () is not taking effect or is overridden by any subsequent inputs.Add()...What is going on here?

Comment: Oh tricky isn't it? The thing is that input is the same so the same object is inserted twice in your list, and when you modify it, it is also updated in the list.

Comment: check dj79's answer for a fix for that problem we overlooked

Answer (score 2):

`preJsonData.inputs = inputs`... The list you are creating in your `MethodName` is not at all connected to the list inside your `preJsonData`.

```
public string MethodName(ref rdServerObjects rdObjects)
{
        RootObject preJsonData = new RootObject();

        List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();
        Input input = new Input();
        preJsonData.username = "xxxx";
        preJsonData.password = "yyyy";
        input.name = "cccc";
        inputs.Add(input);
        input = new Input();    //Add this line to keep from overwriting first
        input.name = "dddd";
        inputs.Add(input);

        //THIS LINE
        preJsonData.inputs = inputs;

        string postJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(preJsonData);
        //string postJsonData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(preJsonData);
        return postJsonData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey you're almost with the same points as I am. Take these 10 extra

Comment: @Phiter And you as well!

Answer (score 2):

As Phiter & Ron have mentioned, you didn't set the `inputs` property of `preJsonData`.

One more part you are missing is, not re-initialising the `input` variable before setting its `name`. This will result in you getting “dddd” in your response.

```
Input input = new Input();
input.name = "cccc";
inputs.Add(input);
input = new Input();
input.name = "dddd";
inputs.Add(input);
preJsonData.inputs = inputs;
```

This would fix your code.

Comment: Awesome...that worked... Thank you all..Appreciate it.